# What is this houseplant that looks like it has a fruit in the curled leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, peace-lily

I've had this plant for a year now, but don't know the name. Can someone help me identify this plant and also tell me how keep him healthy?

Here are the two photos for identification:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This plant is a [Spathiphyllum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathiphyllum) or Peace Lily, a member of the aroid family.  See [this answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/can-this-plant-be-saved/4495#4495) for what happens if they get dry and [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/why-the-leaf-tips-of-my-spathiphyllum-look-burned/5644#5644) for more tips on watering.

They are a reliable indoor plant that likes good access to water.  As they do not have woody stems if they get dry they collapse and look dead.  Watering will return them to their normal appearance.
They tolerate lower light levels but bright filtered light will bring on more flowers and leaf growth.
The only pest problem I ever saw was scale insects.  It cannot be effectively treated with soap and water due to the hiding areas for scale inside the leaf sheaths.