# Know what this plant is?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have had this plant for over 17 years sitting near my kitchen sink near 2 windows.  Some say it looks like a peace lily however never had a white bloom on it.  This had always been a hearty plant and these spikes would appear sometimes.  I have looked for similar plants but haven't had any luck.  These growing spikes are what are throwing the search off.  If you can identify this plant I would greatly appreciate to know the name and where I can get another one.  I live in Michigan and it died from a problem with the window being slightly open when it was below zero.

[image: Wilted after being frozen but spikes are still looking green and lush]

This picture clearly shows the spike growth that no one has been able to identify
[image: Spikes growing from the plant]

The wilted leaf 2 days after the freeze

[image: Wilted leaf]

Answer (score 3):

This is two plants in one pot.  A [spathiphyllum](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/5856/499) or peace lily and another succulent plant which I have seen but cannot identify.  Possibly a member of the [Euphoribiacia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbiaceae) family.  Many members of the family are quite hardier and would be able to resist the cold temperatures that the spathiphyllum could not

Answer (score 2):

The slender leafless plant shown is a *[Psilotum](http://herbaria.plants.ox.ac.uk/bol/plants400/Profiles/OP/Psilotum)*, commonly known as Whisk Fern.
There are two species in the genus, *Psilotum nudum* and *Psilotum complanatum*.
Following the key [here](http://plantnet.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/cgi-bin/NSWfl.pl?page=nswfl&lvl=gn&name=Psilotum), yours looks like *P. nudum* based on the fact that the aerial stems appear to be not flattened and circular to triangular in section.

Answer (score 0):

What color were the spikes that did come up?  Can you describe the blossoms?   The leaves don't look right for an anthurium, but I know there are a ton, so maybe there are some with that type of leaf?

The other segmented plant could be a rhipsalis.  I'm also not very familiar with them but have one. Very trouble free, tough, and low maintenance.  I think they are prehistoric, but not entirely sure about that.  They are segmented, and break fairly easily at the joints.  The one I have gets little white flowers on the ends.  The conditions in your window look like it should get enough light to bloom.